# How can I remove myself from a shared Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-shared-drive

I was part of a shared Google Drive (not a shared folder) and the manager of the drive disappeared. Since I am a viewer of the drive only, is there a way for me to remove myself from the drive? There is no manager listed in the drive itself anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove yourself from a shared drive.

Shared drives belongs to a Google Workspace organization. Ask the organization admin to remove you from the shared drive.

Resources

- [Who is my administrator?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960?hl=en)